# What does it mean for a halogen globe to strobe and then blow?

Tags: light-fixture, halogen

A halogen light globe (bayonet fitting, note this is not a downlight but a traditional globe) in my home started strobing for a while, then it blew. I'm used to incandescent and halogen globes dying quickly once they get the end of their life - they work normally up to the time they blow. Right now my instinct says not to simply replace it (since the replacement will be an LED, which is expensive to replace). There is only one light circuit in the house, and nothing other than this light had problems. I'm in Australia, so the electricity is 240V 50Hz.

So I want to know if this strobing means there may be something else wrong, with the fitting, the wiring, or the switch, or if I should just go ahead and put a new bulb in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen halogen strobe prior to totally failing, I have found 2 causes one was the lamp element itself that was bouncing around causing the flickering then failure, the other failures I have found have been arcing on the contacts. Since LED's draw very little power I would install one and it will probably work, if not cleaning the fixture contacts may do the trick.